# Error when trying to assign a group to a user

Tags: python, django

I am trying to assign a group to a user but without the need to use the django manager, but I run into a problem and it tells me that "<User: island>" must have a value for the field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

This is my view:

```
class UserCreationView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'users.add_user'
    login_url = 'users:login'
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    success_message = 'El usuario fue creado exitosamente'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:user')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        group = Group.objects.get(pk=self.request.POST.get('groups'))
        self.object.groups.add(group)
        self.object.save()
```

Comment: You have to save User first and then add it to group, as the nature of many to many relationship is to have pivot table in which both ids are stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rearrange order of statements

```
    self.object = self.object.save()
    self.object.groups.add(group)
```

Also there is no need to add instance to object you can just use normal variable instead, and your parameter would be better called group/group_id instead of groups

```
   def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        group = Group.objects.get(pk=self.request.POST.get('group_id'))
        user.groups.add(group)
```